# How do I change NSTime format from hh:mm:ss to hh:mm a?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter

I want to change the time format from string, I am having the values in hh:mm:ss in 24 hr format and I want to make it hh:mm:a in 12 hr format.

I have tried -

```
    NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [format setDateFormat:@"hh:mm:ss"];

    NSDate *date123 = [format dateFromString:temp123];
    [format setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
    NSString* newDateString = [format stringFromDate:date123];
```

please help me.

Comment: whats your `temp123` contains

Comment: its a string in hh:mm:ss format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your `temp123` in 24 hour format, then use `HH` instead of `hh`

```
NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[format setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];

NSDate *date123 = [format dateFromString:temp123];
[format setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
[format setAMSymbol:@"am"];
[format setPMSymbol:@"pm"];
NSString* newDateString = [format stringFromDate:date123];
```

Comment: @Harsh - happy to hear

Comment: one more question if you can help - I am getting AM/PM, I want am/pm (i.e small case), is it possible?

Comment: You should not hardcode the AM/PM symbols. It will be confusing to users around the world when unexpected am/pm appears when the expect to see other symbols. Even better, avoid using a hard coded `dateFormat` when creating a date or time string for display to the user. Use a `timeStyle`. Then the user will get a value that matches what they expect to see for their locale.

Answer (score 0):

Try below functions as per your need,

```
+(NSString*)getStringFromDate:(NSDate*)pDate withFormat:(NSString*)pDateFormat{
    NSDateFormatter *dtFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dtFormatter setDateFormat:pDateFormat];
    return [dtFormatter stringFromDate:pDate];
}

+(NSDate*)getDateFromString:(NSString*)pStrDate withFormat:(NSString*)pDateFormat{
    NSDateFormatter *dtFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dtFormatter setDateFormat:pDateFormat];
    return [dtFormatter dateFromString:pStrDate];
}

+(NSString*)dateStringFromString:(NSString *)dateToConver format:(NSString *)fromFormat toFormat:(NSString *)toFormat{
    NSDate *date = [Helper getDateFromString:dateToConver withFormat:fromFormat];
    return [Helper getStringFromDate:date withFormat:toFormat];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your time string is in 24 hrs format.

Objective C

```
NSString *strTime = @"23:10:00";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormater = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormater setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *originalTimeFromString = [dateFormater dateFromString:strTime];
[dateFormater setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
NSString *newDateString = [dateFormater stringFromDate:originalTimeFromString];
NSLog(@"%@",newDateString);
```

Swift 4

```
let strTime = "23:10:00";
let dateFormater = DateFormatter()
dateFormater.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
let originalTimeFromString = dateFormater.date(from: strTime)
dateFormater.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"
let newTimeString = dateFormater.string(from: originalTimeFromString!)
print("Converted Time===>>>",newTimeString)
```